# Setting active class for menu items dynamically in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, navigation

I'm creating a laravel application using bootstrap 4.

I have my main navigation menu in `app.blade.php` . And I have four main blades, About,Product,Contact and Blog.

Then I needed to change the menu item active class according to the current page. As the menu being loaded dynamically from the `app.blade.php` I had to set the active class for current page in the navigation menu dynamically.

What I did was in every blade I've defined a variable called, `$currentpage` and assign page name in to it, assume it's `blog.blade.php`

```
<?php $currentPage = 'blog';?>
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
```

and in the `app.blade.php`,

```
<li class="<?php if($currentPage =='blog'){echo 'nav-item active';}?>">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url('/blog') }}">{{ __('sentence.Blog') }}</a>
                        </li>
```

So this works properly..

but I want to know Is this the correct way of doing it and what are the other possible ways to fulfill my requirement

Comment: Yes, I prefer this way because I used that in my projects

Comment: It's correct. Bt I would suggest using, ternary operator:  `(condition) ? true : false`;

Comment: You can also used session for the page, when particular page is render at time in controller you can set page name in session, here the benefit is you don't need to go for every blade file and set page name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of defining a `$currentPage` variable in the layout files, you could use the
 `request()->is()` method:

```
<li class="nav-item {{ request()->is('blog') ? 'active' : ''}}">
    <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url('blog') }}">{{ __('sentence.Blog') }}</a>
</li>
```

The `is()` method essentially takes the current url path for the request and uses [Str::is()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-is) to check against the pattern you've passed in.

This way you only having to check if the current URL matches the link URL and you don't have to define an extra piece of data somewhere else in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Settings active class for menu items dynamically in Laravel, check below code for PHP blade file to check **multiple array segment** and **set active class** in menu items.

```
@php
    $segment1 = Request::segment(1);
    $pages = array('blog', 'account', 'profile', 'settings');
@endphp
<li class="@if(in_array($segment1, $pages)) active @endif">
    <a href="javascript: void(0);">
        <span>Blog</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make manu active dynamically based on the current route, this code will work

```
<a class="nav-link @if(Route::currentRouteName() =='admin.media') active @endif" href="{{ route('admin.media') }}"> Admin Media </a>
```

User `(Route::currentRouteName()` to get the current route name and match it with the link route, so when the current course will match to link route `active` class will be added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `request()->is('route-name*')` method.
This will also work for all sub-routes of your route.

```
'blog/view/{id}'
'blog/edit/{id}'

<li class="nav-item {{ request()->is('blog*') ? 'active' : ''}}">
    <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url('blog') }}">{{ __('sentence.Blog') }} </a>
</li>
```